# Using Stripe payment form in Meteor

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Strip Payment Form in Meteor:

When putting the Stripe form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 <script
   src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
   data-key=x
   data-amount="2000"
   data-name="Demo Site"
   data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
   data-image="/128x128.png">
 </script>
```

It is not working,

I get it that Meteor doesn't run script in the .html files.
And that I can use the Stripe.js.

But is there a way to use the Form instead of dealing with the Stripe.js?

Comment: how about some links to documentation for both options (stripe.js checkout.js).  Have you looked at Template.*.rendered in docs.meteor.com for initializing your 3rd party js?

Answer (score 14):

I assume you're talking about [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). See the section on Custom Buttons.

Add the script tag for Stripe Checkout in the `<head>` of your template file.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then add a button, anchor, or other clickable tag to your template.

```
<template name="payment">
    <button>Pay</button>
</template>
```

Then add an event to open the form in Stripe's modal window when your button is clicked.

```
Template.payment.events({
    'click button': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        StripeCheckout.open({
            key: 'YOUR PUBLIC KEY',
            amount: 5000,
            name: 'The Store',
            description: 'A whole bag of awesome ($50.00)',
            panelLabel: 'Pay Now',
            token: function(res) {
                // Do something with res.id
                // Store it in Mongo and/or create a charge on the server-side
                console.info(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Stripe will use the "token" function as its callback when the response is returned. The id attribute of that response object is the credit card token, which you use to charge the customer.

Comment: Thumbs up for the 'See the section on Custom Buttons' bit. I couldn't work out for the life of me what the 'Simple' version was on about.

Comment: This is the way to do this. Simple and clean. thank you!